# Specifying mapreduce.map.java.opts without overriding memory settings?

Tags: java, hadoop, memory, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am using a hadoop cluster running mapr 5.2 that has problems with unicode character encodings. I discovered that adding the following lines to `mapred-site.xml` solved this issue:

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Dfile.encoding=utf-8</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Dfile.encoding=utf-8</value>
</property>
```

Unfortunately, this causes many jobs (that work fine without these properties) to throw errors like this:

```
Container [pid=63155,containerID=container_e40_1544666751235_12271_01_000004] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 8.0 GB of 8 GB physical memory used; 31.7 GB of 16.8 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
```

I've tried increasing the value of `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` to the maximum allowed according to this error mesage:

```
Job job_1544666751235_12267 failed with state KILLED due to: MAP capability required is more than the supported max container capability in the cluster. Killing the Job. mapResourceRequest: <memory:16000, vCores:1, disks:0.5> maxContainerCapability:<memory:8192, vCores:20, disks:4.0>
```

But containers are still killed. Like I said, these jobs worked fine before setting the `mapreduce.*.java.opts` properties, so I assume they are overriding something. Is there a way to set `-Dfile.encoding` without overriding other Java parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a value existed earlier for `mapreduce.*.java.opts`? Usually the Java memory settings like `-Xmx` etc goes in there. So just keeping `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` might have removed those settings and that might have affected other jobs. You have two options here

1. Append your encoding settings to the earlier existed value. But here encoding setting will be applicable to all the jobs using that `mapred-site.xml`

```
    <property>
      <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
      <value>your_earlier_existed_java_opts_value_goes_here -Dfile.encoding=utf-8</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
      <value>your_earlier_existed_java_opts_value_goes_here -Dfile.encoding=utf-8</value>
    </property>
```

2. Set this value only to your job while running, provided you use `org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser` on your code. So encoding settings will be applicable only for your job.

```
yarn jar <your_jar> <class> -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts="your_earlier_existed_java_opts_value_goes_here -Dfile.encoding=utf-8"
```

Comment: There are no prior options in mapred-site.xml. Is there some way to have hadoop display whatever options are being passed to it?

Comment: Job configuration can be found from Application master UI (will see a configuration link on left side). First remove the encoding settings from `mapred-site.xml` and submit a job and can find the default value coming for `mapreduce.*.java.opts`. Copy those and then append your encoding settings and make that your `mapreduce.*.java.opts` and see how it goes.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. That worked. Thank you for your help!